# Yii ajax form validation is not submitting

Tags: php, ajax, forms, yii

Hi have the following form declared in a layout:

```
<?php
$regModel = new RegistrationForm();

$form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'registration-form',
    'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl('/utente/sign'),
    'type' => 'inline',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnChange'=>true,  
        'validateOnType'=>true,
        'validationDelay'=>10,
    ),
));

?>
```

the problem is that I don't receive any request on my controller. I tried to monitor the Network Console but I don't see any request as I type in my form.

[image: Network]

I'm using ajax validation on many other forms in my application and they are working as expected.

Any idea why this is not working?

---

**SOLUTION**
Turned out that jQuery was registered twice. The first time by Yii and the second time by my template. Once it was removed from my template everything started working as expected.

Comment: show other view code with fields, error messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check  this [Yii Ajax Validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11729-solved-ajax-validation-not-working-cactiveform/)

Hope this would help.